# skip over closing parentheses in vim

Tags: vim, parentheses

I would like to set up vim so that it moves my cursor right if I press tab on a closing parentheses. This is useful when used with auto complete parentheses.

Here is what I have so far (does not work):

```
inoremap <expr> <Tab> strpart(getline('.'), col('.')-1, 1) == "}" ? "\<Right>" : "\<Tab>"
inoremap <expr> <Tab> strpart(getline('.'), col('.')-1, 1) == ")" ? "\<Right>" : "\<Tab>"
inoremap <expr> <Tab> strpart(getline('.'), col('.')-1, 1) == "]" ? "\<Right>" : "\<Tab>"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Most of the auto-close plugins already do this when you press the closing delimiter.  May want to take a look at one of them to see how they are doing it and change it to use Tab instead of the closing delimiter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There can be only one working mapping to one key (you can define at least two: buffer-local (one per buffer) and one global, but they do not work at the same time), so you need something like that:

```
inoremap <expr> <Tab> stridx('])}', getline('.')[col('.')-1])==-1 ? "\t" : "\<Right>"
```

Don’t use `strpart()`, `string[idx1:idx2]` works fine (all of `idx1`, `idx2`, `:` are optional, but at least one must be present), is less to type and is more readable.

Comment: Thanks! You rock! The only issue I have now is that my tab key does not insert tabs if the cursor is all the way to the right :(